# Multiple One to many relations modelling

Tags: sequelize.js

I have 2 models both of which have a relation to the users table i.e. project users has a foreign key to users, and comments also belong to users

for project users model (`projectusers.js` file):

```
var User = require('./users').table;
var pusers_table = db.define('project_users', { ... });
pusers_table.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(pusers_table);
```

for comments model (`comments.js` file):

```
var User = require('./users').table;
var comments_table = db.define('comments', { ... });
comments_table.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(comments_table);
```

Please note that all three (users, project users and comments) are defined in different JS files and included using requirejs.

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'associationType' of null
        at null.<anonymous> (./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:328:54)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at module.exports.buildAssociatedDaoInstances (./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:324:21)
        at module.exports.transformRowWithEagerLoadingIntoDao (./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:295:37)
        at null.<anonymous> (./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:282:50)
        at Array.map (native)
        at module.exports.transformRowsWithEagerLoadingIntoDaos (./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:281:58)
        at module.exports.handleSelectQuery (./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:262:54)
        at module.exports.AbstractQuery.formatResults (./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query.js:68:34)
        at null.<anonymous> (./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:32:35)
        at Query.Sequence.end (./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:66:24)
        at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:143:8)
        at Query.EofPacket (./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:127:8)
        at Protocol._parsePacket (./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:172:24)
        at Parser.write (./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:62:12)
        at Protocol.write (./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:37:16)
        at Socket.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
        at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:710:14)
        at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
        at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:382:10)
        at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:378:5)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:143:7)
        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:113:10)
        at TCP.onread (net.js:511:21)
```

I just tried upgrading sequelize and am now on sequelize@1.7.0-alpha1 but I still have the issue.

Please note that I do not get an error if I have only one of these defined (i.e. if I remove the relations in comments, project users works totally fine, and vice versa).

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Content of User model please.

Comment: @devius, the code is available at [https://github.com/beaconjs/beacon/tree/master/services/models]. The files in question are comments, users and projectusers.